# Starting with django server

Tags: python, django

I've just created the new django env, but I cannot run the server, because of this error. How to fix it?

```
 0 errors found
    December 02, 2014 - 12:31:33
    Django version 1.6.1, using settings 'mvp_landing.settings'
    Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
    Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
    Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x0283AF30>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Jakub\Desktop\mvp\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py"
    , line 93, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Jakub\Desktop\mvp\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\comm
    ands\runserver.py", line 139, in inner_run
        self.stderr.write("Error: %s" % error_text)
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 19: ordinal
     not in range(128)
```

Comment: Is there any unicode character in your project name ?

Comment: No. I'm doing everything the same like this guy. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3DccH9AMwFQ

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug in django source code.
I just created ticket for it - https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23946

You can edit this problem line manually and see what socket error you got, when runned your server.